# Magento 2 website redirects to older URL

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have moved my **magento project** to another **location**. 
I cleared the

- `var/cache`
- `var/page_cache`
- `var/generation`
- `var/session`
- `var/view_preprocessed`
- and made changed the `core_config_data`

But it is still redirecting to the older URL

Comment: change web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url value in core_config_data.

Comment: its may be permisson problem give 777 permission to var and  pub

Comment: already done the above 2 steps. But its not working

Answer (score 0):

when you visited your new project without changing your url it may create 
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" header.

It will remain cached for as long as the browser's cache can accommodate it.

Please try with another browser or in private mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you moved the magento installation and you created a new database.

Verify if the configuration of the env.php is correct.

/app/etc/env.php

Make sure you point to the correct database.
Save env.php.

You must execute bin/magento cache:flush after saving env.php.
Clear you browser cache, and try to load the site.